# is this HTML input form secure?

Tags: html, regex, forms, input

i managed to build this form using many sources over internet , and it actually works. But do not know if it is good against any breaks.

```
        <form action="/some/server/some.cgi" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>contact me:</legend>
                <input type="hidden" name="recipient"
               value="some@some.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="subject"
           value="message ">
                <br>
                <br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="name" 
                 placeholder="Your Name please" size="30"
            maxlength="30" title="Your name (no numbers)" 
         pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,30}" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            <input type="email" value="email"  
           name="email" placeholder="Provide valid email please" 
                 pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
                title="Your VALID email address" size="30" 
             maxlength="50" required>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="message" 
            placeholder="Message" size="30" maxlength="200"

            title="Long text is not allowed" 
                   pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,200}" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Send" 
                     name="Submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

i am new to regEx and would like to know any issues that can happen with this form. thanks

Comment: The form itself isn't a security concern per se. It's how you treat the input in code behind (esp. when using databases) where you can run into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `One` particular answer whether or not the form is secure. It always depends on the attacker's way of thinking .There many creative ways hackers can think of to bypass a particular form.

> The main place to work on is Server-Side for security Not the
>   Client-Side because Client-Side HTML andJavaScript can be manipulated
>   any how.

Anyways,

You can refer to these links :

```
 code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-orm-keys--net-4753"
 www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATBdUB-aXko"
 www.formstack.com/features/security
```

Answer (score 1):

In the name field you cannot provide space because your regular expression won't allow it.. If you want to allow space please change the below pattern

```
[a-z A-Z]{2,30}
```

Comment: hi, i used third name input for messages and with white space it works for now, i just do not want to add adjustable text area to not ruin sites design. you know any bad issues with name and whitespace?

Comment: if your name field doesnt contains surname means we can skip space or else you should keep space.

Answer (score 1):

The regex will reject valid email addresses. Client side data validation provides no protection against someone trying to subvert your application. The "pattern" attribute is (from memory) a fairly recent addition and ignored by Safarai and older browsers.

What are your criteria for "secure".

Comment: good question about criteria for 'secure',  just dont want to receive bulk messages , or spams. actual security will be over cgi script. i dont like to use captcha and decided if add pattern to form it will be hard for spam bots to fulfill my email.

Comment: You receiving lots of spam is the least of your worries. By using the submited value for the receipient you are exposing an open relay on the internet.